# Error detected while processing ~/.vimrc:

Tags: vim

==> When I tried to open any text files using vim I am getting the error as:

```
Error detected while processing /nfs/home02/sxxj1/.vimrc:
```

==> My `.vimrc` file has below lines only.

```
" set mouse on
set mouse=a

" set color
set term=sun-color

syntax enable

colorscheme evening
```

==> I have tried by deleting the commented lines as well but still getting the same error. Please assist in solving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have more luck on: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is whole error message?

Comment: "Error detected while processing /nfs/home02/sxxj1/.vimrc:" --> This is the whole error msg I am getting. If I press Enter after getting this error msg, the vim editor is opened. But  why the error is being displayed..?

Comment: Try ensuring Unix line endings; write your .vimrc with `:w ++ff=unix`

Comment: Have you tried deleting each line individually to see if any of them fixes the problem?

Comment: Have you tried simply using an empty .vimrc, then adding each line back one at a time?

Comment: Yes. Empty .vimrc file solves this issue. I tried deleting each line as well. "syntax enable" and "colorscheme evening" cause this issue. After deleting both lines, vim is opened without any error. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: If I get the reason for this, I will be more satisfied... :)